# How can I pass a struct in a function with input argument unsigned 32 bit array?

Tags: c, stm32

I want to calculate the CRC value of some data in STM32 micro controller.
The HAL function to calculate the CRC has the following footprint:

```
uint32_t HAL_CRC_Calculate(CRC_HandleTypeDef *hcrc, uint32_t pBuffer[], uint32_t BufferLength);
```

My data are stored in a struct:

```
struct caldata_tag {
    float K_P_Htng;
    uint16_t K_I_Htng;
    uint16_t K_D_Htng;
    uint16_t K_P_Coolg; } caldata;
```

Who is the safest and appropriate way to pass the struct to the HAL_CRC_Calculate() function?

I am thinking about this :

```
#define U32BUFFERSIZE sizeof(struct caldata_tag)/sizeof(uint32_t)
uint32_t buffer[U32BUFFERSIZE];
uint32_t crcValue;

/*  calculate the crc value of the data */
memcpy(buffer,&localStruct,U32BUFFERSIZE);

crcValue = HAL_CRC_Calculate(&CrcHandle,buffer,U32BUFFERSIZE);
```

but I am thinking that is an ugly way, could you tell me if it is ok? OR if you have a better idea?

Comment: Note that the struct might have padding, which can have any value and would give indeterminate results from the CRC function.

Comment: "Who is the safest and appropriate way" and "I am thinking that is an ugly way" --> which is more important for you, safety or beauty.?

Comment: @chux In this case the safety is the prio 1, because I try to write a eeprom emulation module.

Answer (score 3):

> Who is the safest and appropriate way to pass the struct to the `HAL_CRC_Calculate()`function?

Challenges:

- `HAL_CRC_Calculate()` apparently wants to calculate the CRC based on multiples of `uint32_t`.
- The size of `struct caldata_tag` may not be a multiple of the size of `uint32_t`.
- `struct caldata_tag` may contain padding of an unknown state in `caldata`.

Use a `union` of `struct caldata_tag` and a large enough `uint32_t` array.  Zero it, copy the members and then calculate the CRC.

> I am thinking that is an ugly way, could you tell me if it is ok? OR if you have a better idea?

Form a helper function.

```
// Find the quotient of sizeof caldata_tag / sizeof(uint32_t), rounded up
#define U32BUFFERSIZE ((sizeof(struct caldata_tag) + sizeof(uint32_t) - 1)/sizeof(uint32_t))

uint32_t caldata_CRC(CRC_HandleTypeDef *hcrc, const struct caldata_tag *p) {
  // u's size will be a multiple of sizeof uint32_t
  union {
    uint32_t u32[U32BUFFERSIZE];
    struct caldata_tag tag;
  } u = { {0} };  // zero every thing

  // copy the members, not the padding
  u.tag.K_P_Htng = p->K_P_Htng;
  u.tag.K_I_Htng = p->K_I_Htng;
  u.tag.K_D_Htng = p->K_D_Htng;
  u.tag.K_P_Coolg = p->K_P_Coolg;

  return HAL_CRC_Calculate(hcrc, u.u32, U32BUFFERSIZE);
}
```

Use

```
uint32_t crcValue =  caldata_CRC(&CrcHandle, &caldata);
```

---

[Update]

[Further research](http://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/llibre/st/STM32L486xx_User_Manual/group__crc__exported__functions__group2.html) indicates that the `BufferLength` is a count of `uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t` depending on `hcrc->InputDataFormat.`  OP has not provided that, yet if that can be set to `uint8_t`. then code only needs to worry about padding in `struct caldata`.

```
#define U8BUFFERSIZE sizeof(struct caldata_tag)

uint32_t caldata8_CRC(CRC_HandleTypeDef *hcrc, const struct caldata_tag *p) {
  // u's size will be a multiple of sizeof uint32_t
  union {
    uint32_t u32[U32BUFFERSIZE];
    struct caldata_tag tag;
  } u = { {0} };  // zero every thing

  // copy the members, not the padding
  u.tag.K_P_Htng = p->K_P_Htng;
  u.tag.K_I_Htng = p->K_I_Htng;
  u.tag.K_D_Htng = p->K_D_Htng;
  u.tag.K_P_Coolg = p->K_P_Coolg;

  return HAL_CRC_Calculate(hcrc, u.u32, U8BUFFERSIZE);
}
```

If the compiler allows `__attribute__((__packed__))`, [@sephiroth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9815377/sephiroth) answer is a good way to go.

Comment: Wouldn't `u.tag = *p` just be simpler?

Comment: @KamilCuk `u.tag = *p` --> simpler yes, consistent no.   That copes the unknown state of the potential padding bits in `*p`.  For consistent results, those bits need  to be fixed to some value - zero is easiest.  This approach does not depend of prior initialization of `*p`'s padding.

Comment: *Zero it, copy the members and then calculate the CRC.*  The value remaining zero can not be relied upon.  Per [**J.1 Unspecified behavior**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.1): " The following are unspecified: ... The value of padding bytes when storing values in structures or unions"

Comment: @AndrewHenle The padding values remaining 0 itself is not important as much as the values remaining consistent. IAC, your point is still valid.  I shall ponder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pointer that points directly to the beginning of the struct, without having to use the support buffer:

```c
uint32_t *p = (uint32_t*)&localStruct;
```

There are 2 problems with this:

The first one is that you might get unexpected results if the compiler is doing padding on the struct; you can solve this by adding the (packed) attribute to the struct to tell the compiler not to do any padding

```c
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) caldata_tag { 
  //... 
}
```

The other problem is that your structure size isn't a multiple of 32, so it can't be represented in an array of uint32_t without having 16 random bits at the end of the last element. The same goes for your example, bur i think in this case you are discarding the last element of `buffer` because `U32BUFFERSIZE` should be equal to 2, so you are ignoring `K_P_Coolg` and the 16 random bits beside it when calculating the crc.

My suggestion when working with crc and stuff like that is using 8 bit buffers instead of 32 bit ones, as it completely eliminates the latter problem.

Comment: `get unexpected results if the compiler is doing padding` - True. It is wise to remember to set the padding bits to some known certain value, just `memset(...., 0, ..)` the struct before use.

Answer (score 0):

No workaround is needed. According to the documentation for the function HAL_CRC_Calculate: "By default, the API expects a uint32_t pointer as input buffer parameter. Input buffer pointers with other types simply need to be cast in uint32_t and the API will internally adjust its input data processing based on the handle field hcrc->InputDataFormat."

So set the field correctly in the first parameter and you can pass a pointer to bytes to the function.